# How to obtain a snapshot of Google Maps in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, screenshot, google-maps-sdk-ios

In my iOS app, I intend to get a snapshot of my Google Maps map with the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mapView.frame.size)
if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    self.mapView.layer.render(in: context)
}
self.imageSnapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

However, the image returned is a black screen image with the Google Logo on the bottom left. What can I do to get the correct image snapshot of the map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `mapView` is an instance of `GMSMapView`, the following should work

```
let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: mapView.bounds.size).image { _ in
    mapView.drawHierarchy(in: mapView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

This is assuming the map has actually rendered before this code is called of course.